# How to overcome DbUpdateConcurrencyException in EF Core 6 while updating the entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am having the following entity in the code:

```
public class Referral : AggregateRoot<Guid>
{
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<ReferralAccomplishment> ReferralAccomplishments { get; }
}
```

I would like to add new ReferralAccomplishment item to the ReferralAccomplishments collection. The following snippet has been implemented to do so:

```
var referral = await referralRepository.GetAsync(referral => referral.SenderId == GivenReferral.SenderId);
var newReferralAccomplishment = new ReferralAccomplishment();
referral.ReferralAccomplishments.Add(newReferralAccomplishment);
referralRepository.Update(referral);
referralRepository.CommitAsync(); // DbContext.SaveChangesAsync
```

Update method:

```
    public void Update(Referral referral) =>
        _context
            .Referrals
            .Update(referral);
```

The snippet above results in such exception:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); da...
```

The problem as far as I noticed, is that ReferralAccomplishment EF Core context entry has EntityState = EntityState.Modified (for some not understandable reason in my opinion). I would expect it to be EntityState.Added. I'm not sure how to implement this correctly, I would like to have deep update, and I understand there could be need to implement update logic manually, and manage those states manually, but the problem is that new entity state is totally not understandable for me and it results in the mentioned error. How to overcome that? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Does the base class set a PK? Also, why are you calling update in the first place? Adding the new entity and calling SaveChanges should suffice.

Comment: Why do you call `Update`? EF Core tracks changes automatically. You do not need to do that. It is needed if you attach entities, which I do not recommend if entity has navigation properties.